# How to correctly use or in python

Tags: python

I am very new to python and was wondering why this code does not work , I am pretty sure it is my incorrect use of or, however I do not quite understand how ia m supposed to use it.
Here is my simple code

```
continue_shopping=int(input("press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping"))
    if continue_shopping !=0 or !=1:
        print("make sure you enter a valid number")
```

Comment: Did you meant continue_shopping != 0 **and** != 1. With or it will always enter that if statement. Since it can not be 0 and 1 at the same time.

Comment: So basically if i type in 0 , it would say make sure you enter a valid number , if i put in any random number it says make sure you enter a valid number

Comment: Ah , I could use and , now i get a invalid syntax error ,  the equals sign is highlighted in red

Comment: Please provide the actual error message. There are multiple issues in that code, but I cannot guess which one is due to bad copy/pasting and which is the actual issue.

Comment: It says invalid syntax , the equals sign is highlighted in red

Comment: try `if continue_shopping != 0 and continue_shopping != 1:` to fix that syntax error. Also your indentation is wrong, no need for indentation after first line.

Comment: Without the if?

Comment: continue_shopping=int(input("press 0 to stop shopping and print your reciept or press 1 to continue shopping"))
continue_shopping != 0 and continue_shopping != 1:
    print("make sure you enter a valid number") , i get a invalid syntax at the end of the second line

Comment: right, with the if.

Comment: Now it just runs that line as the beggining line of the code

Comment: and look for a basic programming tutorial, the one that talks about syntax and stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 4):

`if continue_shopping !=0 or !=1:` Is invalid syntax.

You have to write `if continue_shopping !=0 or continue_shopping !=1:`

Because isolated `!=1` cant be evaluate into False or True but `continue_shopping !=1` can.

However you should take a look at `or` in your condition. You probably wanted to use `and`.

Comment: you also can use `if continue_shopping >= 2:`

Comment: @УнгамистДолматов unless they type a negative number.

Comment: `continue_shopping !=0 or continue_shopping !=1` is always `True`

Comment: @bereal That was already mentioned in first comment of this question. However question was how to use `or`. Not how to debug my code :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code to:

```
if continue_shopping != 0 and continue_shopping != 1:
```

When it is if continue_shopping !=0 or !=1:
python reads it as if (continue_shopping !=0) or (!=1): which isn't the expected result for you

Comment: Thank you , this is what I have changed it too

Answer (score 0):

1. With Python be careful with proper indenting. Take a look here: [Indenting Code - Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html)
2. You missed another or compare on variable, below is reapired code:

   ```
   if continue_shopping !=0 or continue_shopping !=1:
      print("make sure you enter a valid number")
   ```

Comment: This is caused a strange sensation in my code, these three lines of code work , however they are the first lines that are run in my code when they are in the very end. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: `continue_shopping != 0 or continue_shopping !=1` is always `True`.

Comment: Yes,agree. But maybe he wants to enter some other values too

Comment: May i ask why my answer is not useful?

Comment: Because it contains an obvious logical mistake.

Comment: He was asking why his code isn't working. He did wrong identitation on code, and logical operators were wrong. Ive just answered what he was asking, logical or not, the code is working now. Logical problems are off the scope of this question.